# How decorator run I get a error when I use it

Tags: javascript, decorator, ecmascript-next

I have used webpack and babel to use decorator in my project,when I write like this below:

```
class Man{
    constructor(weight = 10, height = 10){
        this.init(weight, height);
    }
    @decorateWeight
    init(w, h){
        this.weight = w;
        this.height = h;
    }
    toString(){
        return `weight: ${this.weight}, height:${this.height}`;
    }
}

function decorateWeight(target, key, descriptor){
    const method = descriptor.value;
    let moreWeight = 100;
    let ret;
    descriptor.value = (...args) => {
        args[0] += moreWeight;
        ret = method.apply(target, args);
        return ret;
    }
    return descriptor
}
```

It seemed to works correct,But when I add a line like this below:

```
class Man{
    constructor(weight = 10, height = 10){
        this.date = new Date();
        this.init(weight, height);
    }
    @decorateWeight
    init(w, h){
        this.weight = w;
        this.height = h;
        console.log(this.date.getTime());
    }
    toString(){
        return `weight: ${this.weight}, height:${this.height}`;
    }
}
```

when I new a Man instance, I got a error that is "can't call 'getTime' of undefined", I don't get it, where did I make a mistake?

Comment: It`s just for uncertain parameters like this:function fn2(...args){return args.reduce(function(x,y){return x + y})};fn2(1,2,3,4,5);

Comment: Decorators are **not** part of ES7 (ES2016). It's an experimental feature!

Comment: Thxs for mentioning it. I got a little confused with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the line `method.apply(target, …` and the use of an arrow function. The `target` of the decorator is `Man.prototype`, not the instance. Even your first snippet doesn't do what you think it does (you can see it when instantiating multiple objects).

Instead, you should use a `function` for the method, and invoke the original `method` on the current `this` value that will refer to the instance:

```
function decorateWeight(target, key, descriptor){
    const method = descriptor.value;
    const moreWeight = 100;
    descriptor.value = function (...args) {
        args[0] += moreWeight;
        return method.apply(this, args);
    };
    return descriptor;
}
```

Comment: Thanks,It works. I was really misunderstand with it.